# Why are my link clicks for web crawling from a list of links really slow? C#

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping

I want to click on all links with text "300". My code for web-scraping clicks each link really slow. I store the links in a list and click them one by one.

I count the links for indexing then use for(int pos = 0; pos < numberOfElementsFound; pos++). I have tried this code to count and click (By.PartialLinkText("3600") on [https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp] and is very responsive but it is very slow on another site.

```
class Program
{
    private static IWebDriver driver = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://arbitrary.com/");

        clickAllLinks("300");
    }

    //clicking links AND get data
    public static void clickAllLinks(string tagName)
    {
        IWebElement element = 
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='data']"));

        int elements = 
        element.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText(tagName)).Count();

        for (int pos = 0; pos < elements; pos++)
        {
            getElementWithIndex(By.PartialLinkText(tagName), pos).Click();
            //fetchdata();
        }
    }

    public static IWebElement getElementWithIndex(By by, int pos)
    {
        IWebElement element = 
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='data']"));
        IList<IWebElement> elements = 
        element.FindElements(By.PartialLinkText("300"));
        return elements.ElementAt(pos);
    }



    //scrape data
    public static async void fetchdata()
    {
        string currentURL = driver.Url; //url to string
        Console.WriteLine("URL: " + currentURL);

        var httpclient = new HttpClient();
        var html = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(currentURL);

        var htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmldoc.LoadHtml(html); //html to htmldoc

      List<List<string>> Receipt = 
      htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='classname']")
            //htmldoc into list TABLE->TR->TD->InnerText
            .Descendants("tr")
            .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() > 0)
            .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td")
            .ToList())
            .ToList();
```

Comment: It is possible the other site uses rate limiting to prevent web crawlers/scrapers from quickly downloading the contents of the site.

Comment: Possibly. The link opens a new window and I notice the window with all the links I'm clicking from is slightly  freezing up as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplified version of  your `clickAllLinks` method. This will reduce the overhead in your current methods (getting the elements and storing unnecessarly which may impact the execution speed).

```
//clicking links AND get data
public static void clickAllLinks(string tagName)
{
    int elements = 
    driver.FindElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='data']//a[contains(.," + tagName + ")]").Count();

    for (int pos = 1; pos < elements; pos++)
    {
        driver.FindElements(By.xpath("(//div[@class='data']//a[contains(.," + tagName + ")])[" +  pos + "]").Click();
        //fetchdata();
    }
}
```